# Which is the best Image Crop package in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, crop

I am using Laravel to develop an application. In one part, I have to allow user to upload photos. I am planning to use following types of plugins in Laravel. Any idea that what kinds of plugins they are using?

[image]

After uploading, user have to crop image like so-

[image]

Any idea that how can I do so?

Comment: try http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel

Comment: @echoashu I used this, however its not support image crop selection box (can be resize)

Comment: This is actually front end here you will use some js library to send to laravel the co ordinates from where using may be intervention package you can crop the image using the co ordinates.

Comment: I see... @ARIFMAHMUDRANA, so, what JS front end library you suggest for crop?

Comment: use jQuery image cropping library and then handle that in your code 
https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/ is an option and then after submit you can handle like this 
http://image.intervention.io/use/basics#editing

Comment: you should try use cropjs

Comment: @tisuchi you can either use https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs it might have a plain js library & a jQuery version also

Comment: I use the jcrop, http://jcrop.org/

Comment: TQVM @ARIFMAHMUDRANA and Cor Bosman

Comment: I found a complete tutorial here http://howsolve.com/image-crop-with-laravel54-intervention-and-cropperjs-jquery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple plugins available for image handling in Laravel. I think you can use `Intervention Image` for your purpose.

https://github.com/Intervention/image

Comment: complete tutorial http://howsolve.com/image-crop-with-laravel54-intervention-and-cropperjs-jquery/